# My Lambert Material Box no longer renders on Chrome & Firefox after updating to Three.JS r71(&r73)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a slowly rotating cube that works in Chrome, FF, IE on ThreeJS r67-r70 but breaks in Chrome and FF when I use ThreeJS r71, r72, r73.

In the broken version, the cube itself doesn't seem to render, although it does seem to cast a shadow on the axes.

- http://codepen.io/jpflathead/pen/vNaBZa (r70) (working)
- http://codepen.io/jpflathead/pen/bVjbRP (r71) (broken in Chrome & FF, working in IE)

I've linked to two codepens, one forked from the other, the only difference is the version of three.js they include. The original was taken from a Microsoft three.js tutorial, but like several other tutorials I've encountered, it breaks when I change it from the original three.js version to the current one. And more precisely, the break seems to occur moving from r70 to r71, but it is still broken in r73 (the latest release.)

The break seems probably related to the lighting and rendering of Lambert Materials but I am not certain of that.

I can't find any announcement that things would break and why, so I am wondering what happened in r71 to break things? How has three.js changed, and what do I have to do now to render this simple cube?

The biggest clue I have is that

github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration#r70--r71 says:

```
r70 → r71
Removed ambient from Material.
```

But at my n00b stage, I don't know what that means and it doesn't tell me how to fix it.

So what did I do wrong and/or is this a bug in Three.JS?

Comment: Both codepens work for me (Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m) and (Firefox 41.0.2)

Comment: both work for me as well.

Comment: Thanks, so then, ... graphics card??